# Typescript / Next-Auth getSession not working

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I am learning typescript. My next-auth is not working in profile page.
In profile page I have 2 backend files.
First backend file is to get data from mogno.In this file Session is working.
In second file to edit username, session is undefined.
Can you please tell me why one file is ok and another is not?
How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';


interface User {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
}

const Profile = () => {

 const { data: session } = useSession()

 const [editName, setEditName] = useState<string>('')
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
 const [userLoading, setUserLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
 const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState<User>()
 const [userId, setUserId] = useState<string>('')


 const getData = async () => {  // GET USER INFO FROM MONGO
 
    try {
      setUserLoading(true)
      const res = await axios.get('/api/getProfile' )
      setUserProfile(res.data)
      setUserId(res.data._id)
      setUserLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      setUserLoading(false)
    }
 }


 useEffect(() => {
  getData()
 },[])


 const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {  // EDIT USER
    e.preventDefault()
      try {

       setLoading(true)
       await axios.put('/api/editProfile', {userId, editName })
       getData()
       setEditName('')

     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
       setLoading(false)
     } 

    }
 



  return (
    <>
     
      <h3 className='text-center mt-5 pt-5'>Profile User</h3>

      <div className="profileBox">
          // SHOW PROFILE
        <div className="userData">
          <h3 className='text-center'>User Profile</h3>
          {userLoading ? <p>...</p> : <p>Name:  {userProfile?.username}</p>}
          {userLoading ? <p>...</p> : <p>Email: {userProfile?.email}</p>}

          
        </div>
    
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h3 className='text-center'>Edit Profile</h3>
          <input type="text"
                 value={editName}
                 placeholder='Edit Name'
                 className='w-100 my-2 py-1 px-2 '
                 onChange={e => setEditName(e.target.value)}
                 />
          
          <button  className='btn btn-outline-primary w-100 mt-3 rounded-1'
                   type='submit'
                  >
            Edit  
          </button>       
        </form>

      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

backend file to get profile, here I am getting data and SESSION is working

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import User from "@/modules/User"
import {connectToMongoDB} from '../../utils/db'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';


const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {

  const session = await getSession({ req });
  console.log(session)
  if (!session) {
    return res.status(401).send('signin required');
  }

  const { user } = session;
  const email = user?.email

 connectToMongoDB().catch(err => res.json(err))

 const Profile = await User.findOne({email})
 res.status(200).send(Profile)
}

export default handler
```

here is another file for editing name and SESSION is undefined

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import User from "@/modules/User"
import {connectToMongoDB} from '../../utils/db'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    console.log(session)

  connectToMongoDB().catch(err => res.json(err))

  const id = req.body.userId
  const editN = req.body.editName
  const Profile = await User.findById(id)

 Profile.username = editN
 
 await Profile.save() 
 res.status(200).json({ message: 'success '})
}

export default handler
```